# How to scale down the values so they could fit inside the min and max values

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

I have 6 graph bars with the prices.
Each **price number** will represent its graphbar's height by respecting `min` and `max` heights.
What i want is that graph bar's height wouldn't go below or above the `min` and the `max` value.

So i have values of `min = 55` and `max = 110`.
And `price numbers` are:

1. 49
2. 212
3. 717
4. 1081
5. 93

By which mathematical algorithm I could achieve expected results ?
It's some sort of dynamic scalable bar graphs.

**Modified**
So the min and max values from the price list will be: `49(min price) => 55(min)` and `1081 (max price) => 110(max)`

Comment: Do you mean to say in the example above, 49 => 55, and 1081 =>110??

Comment: A key aspect is missing: What are you trying to show in the graph? What is its purpose? What do you want the reader to derive from seeing it?

Comment: @Thrustmaster - YES! Exactly! I will correct a description text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is simple:

- Pick the smallest, and largest item and find the difference.
- (largest_item - smallest_item) maps to (max-min).
- Compute `ratio = (max-min)/(largest_item-smallest_item)`
- `final_value = min_value + ratio*(value-smallest_item)`

As a mathematical function:

```
f(x,max,min,largest,smallest) = min + (max-min)/(largest-smallest)*(x-smallest)
where:
x : Input item's price
max: Maximum value (here, 110)
min: Minimum value (here, 55)
largest: Largest item in input (Here, 1081)
smallest: Smallest item in input (Here, 49)
```

One check, as @amit correctly points out: Ensure largest and smallest item are distinct.

---

So let x = 93. We have other 4 values with us.

```
f(x,max,min,largest,smallest) = min + (max-min)/(largest-smallest)*(x-smallest)

value = 55  +   ((110-55)/(1081-49)) * (93-49)
value = 57.344961
```

Further,

```
f(93,110,55,1081,49) = 57.344961
f(49,110,55,1081,49) = 55
f(1081,110,55,1081,49) = 110
```

Comment: So let the `x = 93`. Calculating: `55 + (110-55) / (1081 - 49) * (93 - 49)` => `110 / (1032) * (44)` equals `4,6899` ?

Answer (score 1):

The function:

```
[(x - min ) / (max-min)*55] + 55
```

ensures the boundaries you are after - but you should also consider - what should the graph show? What do you want the reader to understand from it?

Why?

- `(x-min) / (max-min)` gives a number in range `[0,1]` - 0 for `min`,
  1 for `max`.
- Multiplying it with 55 ensures a number in range `[0,55]`.
- Adding 55 ensures a number in range `[55,110]` - as expected.

(*) Note: for max = min - the above fails because of division with 0, take care for these cases manually.