# Scaling Data Down Large Values To Fit In A Much Smaller Scale

Tags: c#, algorithm, charts, componentone

So what I am attempting to do is take an array of large numbers say from 0 - 600K and scale them down so that they are represent the same trend but in a range of about .5 - 1.5.

Here is the situation...

1) The RED bar represents a Sales Amount.
2)  The BLUE line represents the Price Per Unit.
3) The PINK line represents a budget amount for Price Per Unit.
4) The GREEN line should represent a budget line for Sales Amount.

[image: Chart]

Let me map out what I have tried to to do and give you some insight into what I need to accomplish.

The scale on the left, (ChartGroup0), is used to represent the line graphs and the scale on the right, (ChartGroup1), is for the bar graph. The data being fed to the PINK and BLUE lines are in a range of .5  - 1.3; However, the GREEN lines data ranges from 0 - 600K.

The control that I am using `C1Chart` consists of a maximum of two ChartGroups and each chart group can only have ONE associated chart type. This means that if I want to have a GREEN line graph, to represent the Sales Amount Budget, and have it scale to match the scale on the right, I would have to add it to the (ChartGroup0) and scale the values down to fit in the left scales range.

This is where I am having a problem. I have tried to use an algorithm I found here on stackoverflow but to no avail. ([How to scale down the values so they could fit inside the min and max values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121012/how-to-scale-down-the-values-so-they-could-fit-inside-the-min-and-max-values))
I cannot seem to come up with a way to accurately scale values down to represent the same trend.

I know this may be a bit confusing so feel free to ask any questions and I thank you in advance for any type of direction you may be able to give me.

Best reguards,
Nick

**p.s.** The image is an example of what the chart should look like, not what it     currently has the ability to do. The values and scales will also be dynamic but I believe coming up with a way to determine max and min will not be a problem once I can find an accurate scale down algorithm.

Comment: If your values are in the 100k range and you want them in the 0.0-9.0 range, just divide them by 100,000. 906,134/100,000 = 9.06134 ~ 9.06.

Comment: The values can be from 0 - 5M in some cases and need to be scaled down somewhere between .5 - 1.5.

Comment: So, convert the number to a string, check it's length and: `if(numLength == 6) { /* divide by 100k */ }` `if(numLength == 7) { /* divide by 1000000 */ }` etc... Of course, you may want to use an enum for the lengths instead of magic numbers, but that's entirely up to you.

Comment: What you are suggesting is scaling down by a factor of 10 which is not what I'm trying to accomplish. By your example say the first value input into the chart was 500K, which would scale to 5. This is well out of the Price Per Unit range of .5 - 1.5, what I am trying to do is scale it down so it will represent the same trend while also linking up with the scale values on the right side.

Comment: I didn't understand you're original question than. If you want to **normalize** your data, please take a look at this post [normalization - How to normalize data to 0 to 1 range](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range). It should give you a nice jumping off point.

Comment: What I am trying to do is represent the the GREEN line, which has large values and would fit the scale on the right perfectly, on the left scale. The reason for this is because the right scale is used for a **BAR** type graph and the left is used for a line. I cannot mix chart types on the same scale. So for example the left scale value of 1.2 would roughly match the right scale value of 500K. So my input would be 500K and I would want it to return a roughly 1.2 so that visually data can be looked at from the right scale even though the data behind it is in accordance with the left scale.

Comment: Well, if you want to normalize the data so that 200k = 0.5 and 600k = 1.5, then it's as simple as: ((`value`- 200,000) / (600,000 - 200,000)) + 0.5.  FYI, the stated goal (in text) does not match the example in the image.  The image has 0 = 0.5 and 600k = ~1.26.

Comment: @WyattEarp thank you for the explanation. I believe your solution is what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @nick C1 has launched a new FlexChart control which could very well resolve your issue without needing complex calculations. You can refer [this](http://www.componentone.com/Studio/Pages/Samples/winforms-c1charttoflexchart) and [this](http://our.componentone.com/2016/04/13/exploring-chart-data-series-options-with-flexchart/)